# Typesafe assign to object at key from string

Tags: typescript, keyof

I'm trying to figure out how to create a typescript setter function which takes in an object, a key of that object, and a value to assign at that key.

Here's what I have so far:

```
const setter = <T, K extends keyof T>(obj: T, key: K, value) => {
  obj[key] = value
}

const obj = {
  a: 1,
  b: 'two',
}

setter(obj, 'a', 2) // works fine
setter(obj, 'c', 3) // correctly fails since `obj` does not have a `c` prop
setter(obj, 'b', 4) // works but should not be possible
```

How can I type this function such that `value` matches the type at `T[K]`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sure, just type `value` as `T[K]`

```
<T, K extends keyof T>(obj: T, key: K, value: T[K])
```